# Identity new table foreign key to AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am creating a new table (Let's call it Chart) under MVC Identity which consists of 2 columns (PatientId and DoctorId) that will refer back to the Id column of AspNetUsers. The new table will also have a PK of its own. The following is the *IdentityModels* class.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
{
  public virtual Chart Chart { get; set; }     
  ...
}

public class Chart 
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; } 

   //How to FK the following two params?
   public string PatientId { get; set; }
   public string DoctorId { get; set; }

   public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; } // navigation property    
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> 
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
          : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) {
}

public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Chart> Chart { get; set; }

public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
{
   return new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

May I know how I can refer both my PatientId and DoctorId back to the Id column of AspNetUsers table?

It will be a one-to-many relationship (One DoctorId can have many PatientId, but one PatientId can only be attached to one DoctorId).

Comment: The way you've designed this, you've created a many-to-many relationship.  You can have two charts pointing to the same patient but different doctors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm correct in assuming that both `Patient` and `Doctor` are in fact "users", then you should actually inherit them from `ApplicationUser`.

```
public class Patient : ApplicationUser
{
    // patient-specific properties

    [ForeignKey("Doctor")]
    public string DoctorId { get; set; } // IdentityUser's PK is string by default
    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}

public class Doctor : ApplicationUser
{
    // doctor-specific properties

    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}
```

By default, Entity Framework employs single-table inheritance, so in this configuration, you won't actually end up with separate tables for `Doctor` and `Patient`. Instead, all the properties of both will be added to `AspNetUsers`. For the most part, this is not an issue. The only time it can be problematic is if you need to require a property specific to just one subclass, such as `Doctor`. All properties on subclasses in this configuration must be nullable, since there is logically no way to provide a required value for `Doctor` when saving `Patient`. However, this is only enforced at the database-level. You're still free to validate an input in a form, for example, as being required, even if the table-column backing it is not.

That said, there are other strategies you can use. In this case, the most appropriate alternative would be TPT, or Table-Per-Type. Here, you get a table for each discrete type, `ApplicationUser`, `Doctor,` and `Patient`. Then, on the subclasses (`Doctor` and `Patient`) a foreign key is added to `ApplicationUser`. It is that `ApplicationUser` instance that holds the true "id" for the entity. To use TPT, it's as simple as adding the `Table` attribute to each class:

```
[Table("Doctors")]
public class Doctor : ApplicationUser

[Table("Patients")]
public class Patient : ApplicationUser
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding `Chart`, with this setup, your implementation would look like:

```
public class Chart 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("Patient")]
    public string PatientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Doctor")]
    public string DoctorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, they are both users that have an account registered in AspNetUsers. But what I'm trying to achieve is have 1 table with 2 columns (PatientId and DoctorId) which will reference (FK) the Id column of AspNetUsers. Of course, this new table will also have a PK on its own.

Comment: You're essentially talking about a TPT inheritance strategy (see my updated answer), which effectively creates the same scenario. However, you're better off actually using inheritance rather than manually creating a foreign key, for a whole host of reasons. If doctors and patients are users, then they should be modeled that way in the system.

Comment: I ran your method of inheritance, and after adding a migration and updating the database, my AspNetUsers table now have 2 new columns, DoctorId and Discriminator. May I know what is the Discriminator column for?

Comment: Discriminator is to know which class should be newed up. The values will be either `"Doctor"`, `"Patient"` or `"ApplicationUser"` depending on which was saved.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will look further into the details you've provided!

Comment: Oh. It just occurred to me that you may have taken me too literally. I provided the code with `Doctor` using the `Table` attribute as an example, but intended for you to do the same with `Patient`. With both using TPT, I don't think you should have a discriminator column at all. Rather just `DoctorId` and `PatientId` (as part of the one-to-one makes the inheritance work).